# Error en mostrar resultados obteniendo valores por método Get

Tags: php

Tengo un error en mostrar los resultados al modificar la **Urls** de otra forma distinta a la registrada en la base de datos.

Si creo una **Urls** distinta a la referente de la base de datos **ejemplo:**

```
http://localhost/practica/productos/servicio-web-basico/
```

Me muestra el siguiente error:

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\article.php on line 226

La linea **226** se refiere `<?php echo $title; ?>`

Pero si continuo con la **Urls** normal, no muestra ningún error:

```
http://localhost/practica/servicio-web-basico/
```

La columna de la tabla

```
id_service             url               title
    1          servicio-web-basico/     Servicio Web
```

**Mi consulta**

```
  if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE url='".$id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id_service'];
            $title = $row['title'];
        }
    }
  }
```

Cómo puedo acortar la impresión del método `$_GET` la ultima **Urls** o el ultimo dato de la **Url**
 es decir `servicio-web-basico/` sin importar que tan larga este modificada la **Urls**  `/g/f/producto/servicio-web-basico/`

Para así evitar registrar en la tabla el siguiente dato para evitar el error:

```
id_service             url                               title
    1          /g/f/producto/servicio-web-basico/     Servicio Web
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es obtener la última parte de la url, puedes usar [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.basename.php):

> Dada una cadena que contiene una ruta a un archivo o directorio, esta
>   función devolverá el último componente de nombre.

Ejemplo: **[`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/WUP22336)**

```
$url="http://localhost/practica/productos/servicio-web-basico/";
echo basename($url);
$url="http://localhost/g/f/producto/servicio-web-basico/";
echo "\n";
echo basename($url);
```

#### `Resultado`:

```
servicio-web-basico
servicio-web-basico
```